# Pip Install Spyder on Windows 10 (Won't Start)

Tags: python, windows, installation, spyder

I seem to be unable to uninstall Spyder using Pip with Python 3.7.0 on Windows 10 version 1607 build 14393.  Once it finishes installing, typing "spyder3" into PowerShell creates a brief spinning wheel, and then does nothing.

I verified this problem in a Windows virtual machine of the same version, installing Python 3.7.0 brand-new, pip installing spyder, and then still having the same issue.

Here's the output I got when installing it (maybe something helpful is in there, I don't know)

```
PS C:\Users\Jack\Downloads> pip install spyder
Collecting spyder
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/a6/41b210caa17b9e7336a781fd35a63c0e90b4989f336060e12caf93f3bd70/spyder-3.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.8MB 6.6MB/s
Collecting qtconsole>=4.2.0 (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/7a/8aefbc0ed078dec7951ac9a06dcd1869243ecd7bcbce26fa47bf5e469a8f/qtconsole-4.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (113kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 122kB 5.7MB/s
Collecting pickleshare (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/41/220f49aaea88bc6fa6cba8d05ecf24676326156c23b991e80b3f2fc24c77/pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycodestyle (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/0c/04a353e104d2f324f8ee5f4b32012618c1c86dd79e52a433b64fceed511b/pycodestyle-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB ...
Collecting jedi>=0.9.0 (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/2b/1f188901be099d52d7b06f4d3b7cb9f8f09692c50697b139eaf6fa2928d8/jedi-0.13.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 184kB 11.0MB/s
Collecting pylint (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/c2/b3f73f4ac008bef6e75bca4992f3963b3f85942e0277237721ef1c151f0d/pylint-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (765kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 768kB 6.4MB/s
Collecting numpydoc (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/a8/b4706a6270f0475541c5c1ee3373c7a3b793936ec1f517f1a1dab4f896c0/numpydoc-0.8.0.tar.gz
Collecting cloudpickle (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/d5/efa7cacef5d3bdcd71d7053a698fb9b64a20fff5cb3c592efefa53ea5578/cloudpickle-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyqt5<=5.12; python_version >= "3" (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/83/9acca4c6cc220f29607d857d87bcc1bd645daa4c5f8cff9958f60c5228a8/PyQt5-5.12-5.12.1_a-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win_amd64.whl (49.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 49.4MB 204kB/s
Collecting pygments>=2.0 (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/e5/6d710c9cf96c31ac82657bcfb441df328b22df8564d58d0c4cd62612674c/Pygments-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (849kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 849kB 6.5MB/s
Collecting spyder-kernels<1.0,>=0.4.2 (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2c/8b/45c8778e84ed80dcca57e5eeab1b3bf0b8f65f58bf13eab15b89ba6aaecf/spyder_kernels-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 3.9MB/s
Collecting psutil (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/48/dbcda6d136da319e8bee8196e6c52ff7febf56bd241435cf6a516341a4b1/psutil-5.6.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (230kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 6.6MB/s
Collecting chardet>=2.0.0 (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB ...
Collecting pyzmq (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/70/830668ac324b72157115a919b23e510f9ef5f61ea4d5a6009320f7327638/pyzmq-18.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.1MB 6.5MB/s
Collecting sphinx (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/66/a4af242b4348b729b9d46ce5db23943ce9bca7da9bbe2ece60dc27f26420/Sphinx-1.8.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.1MB 6.4MB/s
Collecting nbconvert (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/39/1e67fea74dc9577cc49f9863fe3ec824e525d1304ab6027d95a94cd586f5/nbconvert-5.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (407kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 409kB 6.6MB/s
Collecting rope>=0.10.5 (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/9b/e92c1d561631da9fbeaf4d5d67ecb65b7d284a63069ee37aec44a2eefae4/rope-0.12.0.tar.gz (246kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 256kB 6.6MB/s
Collecting keyring; sys_platform != "linux2" (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a1/28/0058032477bfdf2003e605d175629963759220661615443e20711446bfa7/keyring-18.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyflakes (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/f2/ed0ffb887f8138a8fe5a621b8c0bb9598bfb3989e029f6c6a85ee66628ee/pyflakes-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 2.9MB/s
Collecting qtawesome>=0.4.1 (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/7f/762f452eef57daf382fc8c16e65026269a96e2f326e4b475008a9adca9de/QtAwesome-0.5.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (628kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 634kB ...
Collecting qtpy>=1.5.0 (from spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/31/4e09942c43cd46050025b8b80c8d8c972dc88807740a49351bd4af41f1ab/QtPy-1.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (43kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 3.3MB/s
Collecting jupyter-client>=4.1 (from qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/c3/3043fe9ffd140d03c9d091a056794ccdc427c56ec19b8eea74f9ea0a498f/jupyter_client-5.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (89kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 5.9MB/s
Collecting jupyter-core (from qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/44/065d2d7bae7bebc06f1dd70d23c36da8c50c0f08b4236716743d706762a8/jupyter_core-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB ...
Collecting traitlets (from qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/d6/abcb22de61d78e2fc3959c964628a5771e47e7cc60d53e9342e21ed6cc9a/traitlets-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB ...
Collecting ipython-genutils (from qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/bc/9bd3b5c2b4774d5f33b2d544f1460be9df7df2fe42f352135381c347c69a/ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipykernel>=4.1 (from qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/b0/f0be5c5ab335196f5cce96e5b889a4fcf5bfe462eb0acc05cd7e2caf65eb/ipykernel-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (113kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 122kB ...
Collecting parso>=0.3.0 (from jedi>=0.9.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/b1/522b2671cc6d134c9d3f5dfc0d02fee07cab848e908d03d2bffea78cca8f/parso-0.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (93kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB ...
Collecting mccabe<0.7,>=0.6 (from pylint->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/89/479dc97e18549e21354893e4ee4ef36db1d237534982482c3681ee6e7b57/mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting astroid<3,>=2.2.0 (from pylint->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/ad/7221a62a2dbce5c3b8c57fd18e1052c7331adc19b3f27f1561aa6e620db2/astroid-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (193kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 6.6MB/s
Collecting isort<5,>=4.2.5 (from pylint->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/89/3137d13dd30a0d063435661950f6dfd50957532989e49aef652f490ef616/isort-4.3.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB ...
Collecting colorama; sys_platform == "win32" (from pylint->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/a6/728666f39bfff1719fc94c481890b2106837da9318031f71a8424b662e12/colorama-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Jinja2>=2.3 (from numpydoc->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/ff/ae64bacdfc95f27a016a7bed8e8686763ba4d277a78ca76f32659220a731/Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB ...
Collecting PyQt5_sip<4.20,>=4.19.14 (from pyqt5<=5.12; python_version >= "3"->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/e5/5e9462008239783720c3eb81d73d2101cc2d5666c2e4db40fe594071d8a7/PyQt5_sip-4.19.14-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl (51kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 3.9MB/s
Collecting packaging (from sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/32/58bc30e646e55eab8b21abf89e353f59c0cc02c417e42929f4a9546e1b1d/packaging-19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5 (from sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting sphinxcontrib-websupport (from sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/69/3c2fbdc3702358c5b34ee25e387b24838597ef099761fc9a42c166796e8f/sphinxcontrib_websupport-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting alabaster<0.8,>=0.7 (from sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/ad/00b090d23a222943eb0eda509720a404f531a439e803f6538f35136cae9e/alabaster-0.7.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from sphinx->spyder) (39.0.1)
Collecting imagesize (from sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/b6/aef66b4c52a6ad6ac18cf6ebc5731ed06d8c9ae4d3b2d9951f261150be67/imagesize-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting babel!=2.0,>=1.3 (from sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/ad/c6f60602d3ee3d92fbed87675b6fb6a6f9a38c223343ababdb44ba201f10/Babel-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.1MB 6.5MB/s
Collecting snowballstemmer>=1.1 (from sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/6c/8a935e2c7b54a37714656d753e4187ee0631988184ed50c0cf6476858566/snowballstemmer-1.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB ...
Collecting requests>=2.0.0 (from sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/e3/20f3d364d6c8e5d2353c72a67778eb189176f08e873c9900e10c0287b84b/requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 3.9MB/s
Collecting docutils>=0.11 (from sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/fa/08e9e6e0e3cbd1d362c3bbee8d01d0aedb2155c4ac112b19ef3cae8eed8d/docutils-0.14-py3-none-any.whl (543kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 552kB 6.6MB/s
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1 (from nbconvert->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/ea/236e2584af67bb6df960832731a6e5325fd4441de001767da328c33368ce/pandocfilters-1.4.2.tar.gz
Collecting defusedxml (from nbconvert->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/1c/17f3e3935a913dfe2a5ca85fa5ccbef366bfd82eb318b1f75dadbf0affca/defusedxml-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting testpath (from nbconvert->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/a4/162f9ebb6489421fe46dcca2ae420369edfee4b563c668d93cb4605d12ba/testpath-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (163kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 6.6MB/s
Collecting entrypoints>=0.2.2 (from nbconvert->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/c6/44694103f8c221443ee6b0041f69e2740d89a25641e62fb4f2ee568f2f9c/entrypoints-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbformat>=4.4 (from nbconvert->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/27/9a654d2b6cc1eaa517d1c5a4405166c7f6d72f04f6e7eea41855fe808a46/nbformat-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 6.6MB/s
Collecting bleach (from nbconvert->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/05/27e1466475e816d3001efb6e0a85a819be17411420494a1e602c36f8299d/bleach-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 6.5MB/s
Collecting mistune>=0.8.1 (from nbconvert->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/ec/4b43dae793655b7d8a25f76119624350b4d65eb663459eb9603d7f1f0345/mistune-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pywin32-ctypes!=0.1.0,!=0.1.1; sys_platform == "win32" (from keyring; sys_platform != "linux2"->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/4b/3ab2720f1fa4b4bc924ef1932b842edf10007e4547ea8157b0b9fc78599a/pywin32_ctypes-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1 (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (226kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 235kB ...
Collecting tornado>=4.1 (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/39/78b68ebe0505a313128d23d336fdd3512b138f4ade936c6c7db9aeba1c1a/tornado-6.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (415kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 419kB ...
Collecting decorator (from traitlets->qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/cd/7c8240007e9716b14679bc217a1baefa4432aa30394f7e2ec40a52b1a708/decorator-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipython>=5.0.0 (from ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/3b/3fcf422a99a04ee493e6a4fc3014e3c8ff484a7feed238fef68bdc285085/ipython-7.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (768kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 778kB 6.5MB/s
Collecting wrapt (from astroid<3,>=2.2.0->pylint->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/b2/0f71ca90b0ade7fad27e3d20327c996c6252a2ffe88f50a95bba7434eda9/wrapt-1.11.1.tar.gz
Collecting lazy-object-proxy (from astroid<3,>=2.2.0->pylint->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/08/23c0753599bdec1aec273e322f277c4e875150325f565017f6280549f554/lazy-object-proxy-1.3.1.tar.gz
Collecting typed-ast>=1.3.0; implementation_name == "cpython" (from astroid<3,>=2.2.0->pylint->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/4e/79a8d30d2d7925bd1b86416a8921e98c5c336a00204c2edbbd9ff420d8a1/typed_ast-1.3.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (153kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 6.6MB/s
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.3->numpydoc->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/c6/2399700d236d1dd681af8aebff1725558cddfd6e43d7a5184a675f4711f5/MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2 (from packaging->sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/0a/001be530836743d8be6c2d85069f46fecf84ac6c18c7f5fb8125ee11d854/pyparsing-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 4.6MB/s
Collecting pytz>=0a (from babel!=2.0,>=1.3->sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/28/1d3920e4d1d50b19bc5d24398a7cd85cc7b9a75a490570d5a30c57622d34/pytz-2018.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 6.2MB/s
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=2.0.0->sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/75/f692a584e85b7eaba0e03827b3d51f45f571c2e793dd731e598828d380aa/certifi-2019.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (158kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB ...
Collecting urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.0.0->sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/00/ee1d7de624db8ba7090d1226aebefab96a2c71cd5cfa7629d6ad3f61b79e/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 122kB 6.5MB/s
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.0.0->sphinx->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 3.9MB/s
Collecting jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 (from nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/69/df679dfbdd051568b53c38ec8152a3ab6bc533434fc7ed11ab034bf5e82f/jsonschema-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 3.9MB/s
Collecting webencodings (from bleach->nbconvert->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/24/2a3e3df732393fed8b3ebf2ec078f05546de641fe1b667ee316ec1dcf3b7/webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/a7/9b1dd14ef45345f186ef69d175bdd2491c40ab1dfa4b2b3e4352df719ed7/prompt_toolkit-2.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (337kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 337kB 6.4MB/s
Collecting backcall (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/71/c8ca4f5bb1e08401b916c68003acf0a0655df935d74d93bf3f3364b310e0/backcall-0.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting pyrsistent>=0.14.0 (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/46/4e93ab8a379d7efe93f20a0fb8a27bdfe88942cc954ab0210c3164e783e0/pyrsistent-0.14.11.tar.gz (104kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 6.6MB/s
Collecting attrs>=17.4.0 (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/96/d828354fa2dbdf216eaa7b7de0db692f12c234f7ef888cc14980ef40d1d2/attrs-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wcwidth (from prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.1->qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/9f/526a6947247599b084ee5232e4f9190a38f398d7300d866af3ab571a5bfe/wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, ipython-genutils, decorator, traitlets, jupyter-core, python-dateutil, pyzmq, tornado, jupyter-client, pygments, parso, jedi, pickleshare, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, backcall, colorama, ipython, ipykernel, qtconsole, pycodestyle, mccabe, wrapt, lazy-object-proxy, typed-ast, astroid, isort, pylint, pyparsing, packaging, sphinxcontrib-websupport, alabaster, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, imagesize, pytz, babel, snowballstemmer, chardet, certifi, urllib3, idna, requests, docutils, sphinx, numpydoc, cloudpickle, PyQt5-sip, pyqt5, spyder-kernels, psutil, pandocfilters, defusedxml, testpath, entrypoints, pyrsistent, attrs, jsonschema, nbformat, webencodings, bleach, mistune, nbconvert, rope, pywin32-ctypes, keyring, pyflakes, qtpy, qtawesome, spyder
  The scripts jupyter-migrate.exe, jupyter-troubleshoot.exe and jupyter.exe are installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts jupyter-kernel.exe, jupyter-kernelspec.exe and jupyter-run.exe are installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script pygmentize.exe is installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Running setup.py install for backcall ... done
  The scripts iptest.exe, iptest3.exe, ipython.exe and ipython3.exe are installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script pycodestyle.exe is installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Running setup.py install for wrapt ... done
  Running setup.py install for lazy-object-proxy ... done
  The script isort.exe is installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts epylint.exe, pylint.exe, pyreverse.exe and symilar.exe are installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script pybabel.exe is installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script chardetect.exe is installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts sphinx-apidoc.exe, sphinx-autogen.exe, sphinx-build.exe and sphinx-quickstart.exe are installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Running setup.py install for numpydoc ... done
  The scripts pylupdate5.exe, pyrcc5.exe and pyuic5.exe are installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Running setup.py install for pandocfilters ... done
  Running setup.py install for pyrsistent ... done
  The script jsonschema.exe is installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script jupyter-trust.exe is installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script jupyter-nbconvert.exe is installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Running setup.py install for rope ... done
  The script keyring.exe is installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script pyflakes.exe is installed in 'c:\program files\python\python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed Jinja2-2.10 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 PyQt5-sip-4.19.14 alabaster-0.7.12 astroid-2.2.5 attrs-19.1.0 babel-2.6.0 backcall-0.1.0 bleach-3.1.0 certifi-2019.3.9 chardet-3.0.4 cloudpickle-0.8.0 colorama-0.4.1 decorator-4.3.2 defusedxml-0.5.0 docutils-0.14 entrypoints-0.3 idna-2.8 imagesize-1.1.0 ipykernel-5.1.0 ipython-7.3.0 ipython-genutils-0.2.0 isort-4.3.15 jedi-0.13.3 jsonschema-3.0.1 jupyter-client-5.2.4 jupyter-core-4.4.0 keyring-18.0.0 lazy-object-proxy-1.3.1 mccabe-0.6.1 mistune-0.8.4 nbconvert-5.4.1 nbformat-4.4.0 numpydoc-0.8.0 packaging-19.0 pandocfilters-1.4.2 parso-0.3.4 pickleshare-0.7.5 prompt-toolkit-2.0.9 psutil-5.6.1 pycodestyle-2.5.0 pyflakes-2.1.1 pygments-2.3.1 pylint-2.3.1 pyparsing-2.3.1 pyqt5-5.12 pyrsistent-0.14.11 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pytz-2018.9 pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0 pyzmq-18.0.1 qtawesome-0.5.7 qtconsole-4.4.3 qtpy-1.6.0 requests-2.21.0 rope-0.12.0 six-1.12.0 snowballstemmer-1.2.1 sphinx-1.8.5 sphinxcontrib-websupport-1.1.0 spyder-3.3.3 spyder-kernels-0.4.2 testpath-0.4.2 tornado-6.0.1 traitlets-4.3.2 typed-ast-1.3.1 urllib3-1.24.1 wcwidth-0.1.7 webencodings-0.5.1 wrapt-1.11.1
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have the same issue when double clicking the "spyder.exe" file located at `C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\Scripts\spyder3.exe`.
Also, I tried the following (in PowerShell):

```
python
from spyder.app import start
start.main()
```

But then I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 178, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 90, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'
```

So I tried `pip install PyQt5`, but it told me the requirement was already satisfied, and trying spyder again afterward was still to no avail.

I am not sure how to resolve this.  It seems like nothing I do will get spyder working.  Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyQtWebEngine is now in [its own package](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtwebengine/download), separate from PyQt5.

Try:

```
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

And then see if you can use Spyder.

See also: https://pypi.org/project/PyQtWebEngine/